# Aws rekonition custom label

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-rekognition

Using my custom labels in aws rekognition i'm trying to upload a image which has multiple labels in it. But instead getting the labels detected in the image im getting one label in reponse. I'm puzzled out what do i miss here. Below is my code to detect custom labels.

```
byte[] imageBytes = file.getBytes();

        Image ri = Image.builder().bytes(SdkBytes.fromByteArray(imageBytes)).build();

        DetectCustomLabelsRequest detectCustomLabelsRequest = DetectCustomLabelsRequest.builder()
                .projectVersionArn("project arn")
                .image(ri).build();

        DetectCustomLabelsResponse response = rekognitionClient.detectCustomLabels(detectCustomLabelsRequest);
//        List<CustomLabel> customLabels = response.customLabels();
        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (CustomLabel customLabel : response.customLabels())
        {
            map.put("Label",customLabel.name());
            map.put("Confidence", String.valueOf(customLabel.confidence()));
            System.out.println("label -> "+customLabel.name());
        }

        return map;
```

Need to find the list of labels in the image passed to the API

Comment: Have you evaluated your model post-training? Your SDK code looks ƒine to me so ensure your model is accurate - refer to: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/customlabels-dg/im-metrics-use.html

Comment: Specify `.minConfidence(0)` for `detectCustomLabelsRequest` and update the question with the output of the program please :)